# in graph data structure using linklist values of nodes are changed

Tags: c++, data-structures

this is a graph data structure using link list.
so i got stuck at the values of node are changed.
im putting output first and then code.
why this is happnning.

## (

this is output in that im printing node values and they changed why

enter no of edges=
4

enter no of nodes
4

#0#1#2#3

#1#2#0#3

enter connection

## )

//here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct graph
{
    int nn;
    int ne;
    struct node *a;
};

struct node
{
    int x;
    node *next;
};
void makegraph(graph *&g)
{

    cout << "enter no of edges=" << endl;
    cin >> g->ne;
    cout << "enter no of nodes" << endl;
    cin >> g->nn;
    g->a = new node[g->nn];
    node *q;
    node *ih = g->a;
    for (int i = 0; i < g->nn; i++)
    {
        ih->x = i;
        cout << "#" << ih->x;
        ih->next = NULL;
        ih = ih + i;
    }
    cout << endl;

    int ii = 0;
    ih = g->a;
    while (ii < 4)
    {
        cout << "#" << (ih + ii)->x;

        ii++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    int t, y;
    node *temp = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < g->ne; i++)
    {

        cout << "enter connection" << endl;

     ****output is of till here****


        cin >> t >> y;
        q = new node;
        q->x = y;
        q->next = NULL;
        g->a = g->a + t;
        temp = g->a;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = q;
        g->a = g->a - t;
    }
    g->a = ih;
}

int main()
{
    graph *g = new graph;
    makegraph(g);
    
}
```

Comment: what does `ih`, `nn`, `ne` mean? Can you please add a comment over their name to explain their abbreviation? (Also, its a really bad practice to name variables this way. Name them with full words, iike `next_node`. else it becomes hard for others to understand your code.)

Comment: `ih = ih + i` doesn't make sense. On the first iteration of the loop, `ih` points to `g->a[0]`. On the second, it again points to `g->a[0]` (since `ih = ih + i` is a no-op when `i == 0`). On the third, it points to `g->a[1]`. On the forth, to `g->a[3]`; `g->a[2]` is skipped. This is how you ended up storing 1, 2 and 3 in nodes 0, 1 and 3. The value in node 2 is actually an uninitialized garbage; it only happens to be zero by accident.

Comment: @ignortandetnik okay got it i have to write ih=ih+1;